# Using LINQ to get a string from a tab delimited text file into an array in the way I want

Tags: c#, string, linq, csv

I have a tab delimited text file that has lines in the following format:

> I000001 \t I000002 \t "Blah blah blah. Blah. Blah Blah"

I'm trying to split the each line on every tab, so the above line would be split into three parts

I've been able to split each line as desired when there's no spaces or quotations, but I'm having difficulty when there is.

Here's what I've tried with a line similar to above:

```
var x = from lines in data
        .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
        .Select(l => l.Split('\t'))
        select new 
        {
         A = lines[0].Trim(),
         B = lines[1].Trim(), 
         C = lines[2].Trim()
        };
```

The above produces an array with indexes [ 0 ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ]. Each index has three member made up of the above string (see image below). It should only only have one index with three members.

[image]

Notice how the first item in the array, has three elements. There are two more items in the array, below the first one. They both also have 3 elements, and these three elements contain the rest of the string that's enclosed in double quotations.

**Solution:**

As per selected answer, there was extra tabs in the sentence inside the quotations, leading to additional items being added to the array. To solve this I used a regex, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148974/need-c-sharp-regex-for-replacing-spaces-inside-of-strings):

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"""[^""]+""", m => m.Value.Replace('\t', ' '));
```

Comment: Not quite sure what your problem is... could you explain it better?

Comment: I assume you are confused because  the debugger window shows `"I000001"`, but it just means that it's a string. Actually it is `I000001`.

Comment: Really?? I thought I explained it pretty well. The string inside the double quotations is being split into several parts, creating more objects in the array than there should be. The string in double quotations (or the third tab) should be at index [2] only, in its entirety.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that has caught me before but I do realise that `"I000001"` is `I000001`. The problem is the string inside the quotations is being splt over three different arrays, and each one of these has three items. If I could get the debugger window to stay open, I'd screen shot and you'd understand.

Comment: You can't reliably do this with LINQ. Use the `TextFieldParser` mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @JimMischel will have a look. Don't understand why the question is being voted to be closed...?

Comment: @TimSchmelter please see attached image.

Comment: Have edited question to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Split('\t')`, this will split on every tab mark... therefore, if your text lines are being split as you say they are, then they must have tab marks in them (in the text between the "" marks). Please check this... if you do, you could use a Regular Expression to remove just the tab marks that appear inside the quotation marks *before* you run your Linq query.

Comment: You're right. The lines of text may have originally been in paragraphs, causing additional tabs? Removing them manually gets it working as desired, but I'll use a regex to remove any inside the quotations.

Comment: Edited your answer with the regex, for completeness.

Comment: @MattSull87, your edit was rejected by several moderators for changing the meaning of the answer or something... perhaps you should add your Regex to the end of your question instead?

Comment: Suppose that makes sense. Will update question shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIo.TextfieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) and set the delimiter to `\t`.

This is actually a really common question, but people are normally asking about commas, not tabs.

Comment: Tried the `TextFieldParser` but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @MattSull87 - Did you set the HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes property?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this code:

```
var data = new[] {"I000001 \t I000002 \t \"Blah blah blah. Blah. Blah Blah\""};

var x = from lines in data
        select (from s in lines.Split('\t')
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
            select s.Trim())
        .ToArray();
```

In this example there is only one tab-delimited string, but if you have more of them in your input array, x will be an enumeration of arrays of strings, composed of tab-delimited subitems.